# Call Functions Based On Query String Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, logic, query-string

On my web app, the user is asked a question and can choose only one of two answers. Yes or no. A query string is created based on their answer.

The following code carries the query string through the URL of every page:

```
var navlinks = document.getElementsByClassName("qString");
    $(navlinks).prop("href", function() { return this.href + location.search; })
```

There are only 2 query strings, `?choice=yes` and `?choice=no`.

Once the user is taken through the app, if they navigate to either `park01.html`, `park02.html`, or `park03.html` from any other page, data will be pulled accordingly via a called `function()`.

Here's my concept in pseudocode:

```
// I assume I should store specific html pages to a variable    
var parkPages = ["park01.html", "park02.html", "park03.html”];

    if (user clicks on specified html pages stored in variable) {

         and the url contains = ?choice=yes;
         Then call these functions: funcA(), funcB(), funcC();
    }
    else {

         the url contains = ?choice=no;
         Then call these functions: funcD(), funcE(), funcF();
    }
```

Does the concept make sense? And what does the syntax look like?

Comment: What is `onClick parkPages`? What syntax?

Comment: I'm working in JavaScript. And the above concept is written in JS pseudocode.

Comment: How is the user "taken through the app"?

Comment: You surely want `location.pathname`, not `location.search`?

Comment: I've never worked with query strings before so this is new to me. I want to call a specific function based on the query strings generated on the `index.html` page. @Bergi The user navigates through the app using the global nav bar. That's what I meant by "taken."

Comment: Why not try it out? Nobody's clear as to what your actual problem is.

Comment: The code written above is just a concept. So the syntax is not explicit. It's just an idea written loosely using JS syntax. There's syntax missing and I don't know what that syntax is. Maybe if I write out the concept in plain English, that may help? I want the program check the query string, then call a function based on said query string. So if `?choice=yes` then call `function a()` and/or `function x()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply looking for a concrete translation of your pseudocode into JavaScript, based on your last comment, this should be what you need:

```
if (location.search === "?choice=yes") {
    funcA();
    funcB();
    funcC();
}
else {
    funcD();
    funcE();
    funcF();
}
```

Though at this stage, I'd recommend spending less time here and more on instructional/tutorial based websites.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I'm doing the instruction/tutorial sites as well, but said sites can't answer my questions. I've learned recently that I've had the answer to JS problems but didn't have the confidence to trust my knowledge.